# ETW Monitoring Process Start / Stop and get Command line

Tags: etw

I want to subscribe my script to ETW to Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process => Process Start event.

But I can't find any way to get the Command line parameters and working directory how my process has started.

Any provider can offer this information?
e.g. Process Start / Fields required: Working Directory, Command Line, and Process description

Any help I would appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. If you monitor windows-kernel-process, there will be no commandline in it.
You need to use NT kernel logger to monitor process events.

This is an example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/configuring-and-starting-the-nt-kernel-logger-session